# Search for folder name in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I search for a folder name and see it in Explorer?

File search using <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> required me to know file name. Sometimes I know the folder which have desired file.

Answer (score 32):

You can search for files in folder `foo` by using cmd+p like `foo/`. You can open a file there, which will cause the Explorer to scroll to that file. But there's no way to search for a folder in the Explorer directly - consider filing a feature request on Github.

Comment: Via the UI, you can click on Go then Go To File...

Answer (score 28):

I see this is an old post, but it looks like you can do it now. I stumbled on it. Click on any directory in the sidebar Explorer to focus the Explorer, and then just start typing. You'll see a red text box in the upper right of the sidebar with your text, and the Explorer will start finding your directory.

[image]

Comment: Nah this doesn't work good enough it doesn't search nested folders it hey are not opened (for example if scripts contains a folder named rich-text ,it wouldn't be found)

Comment: Also that little button/icon between "rich-text" and "X" is pretty handy. It toggles whether or not things that don't match the search are displayed.

Comment: Oh nice, it fails at showing you the path, but if you use that little filter icon, it'll display only directories that have items in it that match the query! This works. Thanks, @MyiEye.

Comment: It was there I remember, but isn't anymore.

Answer (score 19):

You can <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and search for `<folder_name>/` and open some file from that folder to reveal it in the explorer.
Sadly I couldn't find any way to search for folder from the explorer itself :(

Answer (score 7):

Late answer, however this is now available!

in Settings in visual studio code, change Workbench > List: Keyboard Navigation to "filter". Then, when you go to the tree view of the file explorer and start typing, all files and folders that does not match the text are filtered, leaving only the files and folders that matches the text. It searches through all levels of the tree.

[See an example of the setting here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q7OT.png)

Comment: it says 'Value is deprecated' now.

Answer (score 5):

I've also been searching for such feature after switching from JetBrains products.

Unfortunately, it's not implemented yet. But there is an issue on Github with a proposal:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10026